# getting list of entities matching same tags sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, select

I have 2 entities, say entity [x] and [y]. both entities are associated with some tags. entity [y] is used to search for similar [x] entities. For ex. if entity [y] consist of tags "books" and "blogs", I want a list of all the [x] entities having both of those tags.

My table schema is:

```
[x] 
entity_id int    // its a foreign key from entity table  
tag varchar      // this is the tag to be matched
(one entity can have multiple tags hence multiple rows of same entity
id will be inserted)


[y]
entity_id int    // again a foreign key from entity2 table
tag varchar      // tags again
(same comment comes here too)
```

One more example, say I have a [y] entity_id 10, and this 10 entity_id is associated with 3 tags, say "bus", "train" and "plane", when I want to look up using this entity_id 10, I want a list of [x] entity_ids associated with all these 3 tags. [x] entity_id can also have additional tags too.

Comment: In your case can the `x` entity_id be associated with some additional tags (except those 3)?

Comment: yes, it can. It should have all those tags. Can have extra few too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a `y.entity_id` as a parameter, `10` in this example, this query returns every `x` record that doesn't have an instance where there is a `y` record that doesn't have a corresponding `x` record:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    x
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM 
        y LEFT JOIN
        x subX 
            ON subX.tag = y.tag
            AND subX.entity_id = x.entity_id
    WHERE 
        y.entity_id = 10
        AND subX.entity_id IS NULL  
)
```

Comment: can you please elaborate a little?